# Visual Studio 2008 IIS Debugging - Debugging stops automatically after time

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, iis-7

We are investigating a problem with a site we created that only exists on out production server.

We have installed Visual Studio and have the source code loaded. We start debugging and the site loads, but when we come back after say an hour (it might be less) debugging has stopped.

I found a site that said to disable Pings in IIS7, but that doesn't seem to work either!

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging you need to increase your session timeout in the `web.config`. Look for `sessionState` and `timeout`. Also there is a httpRequest timeout whcih you might need to increase.